# Jsonschema xxx is not of type object

Tags: python-3.x, jsonschema

I use python and json schema as the data validator tool, below is my schema:

```
    ValidatorSchema = {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["data"],
        "properties": {
            "data":
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": ["account", "password", "clientType"],
                    "properties": {
                        "account": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "password": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "clientType": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "enum": [ClientTypeEnum.USER_EMAIL.code, ClientTypeEnum.USER_MOBILE.code,
                                     ClientTypeEnum.USER_MINA.code,
                                     ClientTypeEnum.USER_WECHAT.code]
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

and my data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "account": "ccl",
        "password": "12345678",
        "level": 0,
        "client_type": 100
    }
}
```

but the validator always show me errors, how can I fix it:

```
SchemaError: b'{\n    "data": {\n        "account": "ccl",\n        "password": "12345678",\n        "level": 0,\n        "client_type": 100\n    }\n}' is not of type 'object'
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass the data as a string into the validation function?
Can we see the code where you're importing the JSON and passing it to the function too please?

Comment: After using jsononpickle.decode(request.data) to process the data,  it's ok now.

Answer (score 2):

Your schema says that the following fields are required:

```
["account", "password", "clientType"]
```

However, your json has:

```
{
    "account": "ccl",
    "password": "12345678",
    "client_type": 100 // <-- Can you spot the difference?
}
```